# Convert epoch time in Data Factory to datetime

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, epoch

I have the following query.  This query copies the data from `Cosmos DB` to `Azure Data Lake`.

```
select c.Tag
from c
where 
c.data.timestamp >= '@{formatDateTime(addminutes(pipeline().TriggerTime, -15), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'
```

However, I've got to use the `_ts` which is the epoch time when the document was created on the `cosmos DB` collection instead of `c.data.timestamp`.  How do I convert epoch time to date time and compare with it with `'@{formatDateTime(addminutes(pipeline().TriggerTime, -15), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'`

I have also tried using 
    `dateadd( SECOND, c._ts, '1970-1-1' )` which clearly isn't supported.

Comment: It looks like Cosmos doesn't implement the DateAdd function. Maybe you can use the [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks) function in Data Lake and manipulate that value into a Unix timestamp that you can compare with the _ts value.

Comment: Have you looked at using a user defined function at all? JavaScript's Date class can do what you're looking to do.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I can add UDFs in Stream Analytics, but where do I add them in the data factory pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Chris said, you could use [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) in cosmos db query.

udf:

```
function convertTime(unix_timestamp){
      var date = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);
      return date;
}
```

sql:

[image]

You could merge it into your transfer sql:

```
select c.Tag
from c
where 
udf.convertTime(c._ts) >= '@{formatDateTime(addminutes(pipeline().TriggerTime, -15), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'
```

Comment: Thanks Jay for an in depth answer, It is working perfectly.